# How do I remove accounts using the Geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I have several accounts I've created in the Geth console using:

```
personal.newAccount()
```

I no longer use (nor have any intention of using) the first couple of accounts I created, meaning whenever I reference an active account I have to set the account array index to something other than `0`.

How do I remove the unused accounts so I can just reference my active account using `eth.accounts[0]`?

Comment: I cannot access the keystore files on Ubuntu. When I type $ geth account list it gives me a list of accounts and the directory of these keystore files but I cannot find this folder anywhere on this machine. Can someone please help and tell me how to access the keystore files? I am new to linux and feel that it has to do with permissions..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't remove account. You need to remove them directly from your keystore folder.

**IT IS IRREVERSIBLE.**

`~/Library/Ethereum/keystore`

I feel the need to repeat that once the file is deleted it's Game over.

Comment: This removes the reference to those accounts in `eth.accounts`, but how does `eth.coinbase` get updated? (It's now pointing to one of the deleted accounts.)

Comment: next account in line should become eth.accounts[0]. What do you get ?

Comment: Yep, correct - the accounts entries have shuffled up, which is great. But the `eth.coinbase` variable hasn't updated and now points to the original `account[0]`, which was deleted, and not the new one.

Comment: Are you trying to mine ? `geth -mine --etherbase "youraccountaddress"`.

Also you might want to try `geth account update "address"`

Comment: Not on this box, but I wanted to know for future reference. I've found the command required for setting it: `web3.miner.setEtherbase(web3.eth.accounts[0])`

Answer (score 2):

for testnet it's in `~/Library/Ethereum/testnet/keystore`